# How to convert Australia related EPSG in pyproj?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj, australia

I want to convert longitude (`151.209900`) and latitude (`-33.865143`) into Australia related EPSG (`4283` and `7844`) by using **pyproj** library.

I have tried:

```py
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
transformer = Transformer.from_crs('epsg:4326', 'epsg:4283')
print(transformer)
# Output: proj=noop ellps=GRS80

# Sydney
x = 151.209900
y = -33.865143
point = transformer.transform(x, y)
print(point)
# Output: (151.2099, -33.865143)
```

I get the same outputs with `EPSG:7844`.

It seems that pyproj is able to recognize `EPSG:4283` and `EPSG:7844` but it just does not convert. I am using **pyproj** `3.0.0.post1` version.

**Could you tell me if it is possible to do such conversions? If not could you recommend a library for doing it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EPSG:4283` (https://epsg.io/4283) and `EPSG:7844` (https://epsg.io/7844) are datums, not projections. This is why transformations are not possible here.